# ZeroMQ connect to physically non connected socket

Tags: zeromq

I'm trying to understand if ZeroMQ can connect pub or sub socket to non existing (yet) ip address. Will it automatically connect when this IP address will appear in the future?
Or should I check up existance first before connecting?
Is the behavior same for PUB and SUB sockets?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is buried somewhat in the manual, [here](http://api.zeromq.org/master:zmq-connect):

> for most transports and socket types the connection is not performed immediately but as needed by ØMQ. Thus a successful call to zmq_connect() does not mean that the connection was or could actually be established. Because of this, for most transports and socket types the order in which a server socket is bound and a client socket is connected to it does not matter. The ZMQ_PAIR sockets are an exception, as they do not automatically reconnect to endpoints.

As that quote says, the order of binding and connecting does not matter. This is extremely useful, as you don't then have to worry about start-up order; the client will be quite happy waiting for a server to come online, able to run other things without blocking on the connect.

**Other Things That Are Useful**

The direction of bind/connect is independent of the pattern used on top; thus a `PUB` socket can be connected to a `SUB` socket that has been bound to an interface (whereas the other way round might feel more natural).

The other thing that I think a lot of people don't realise is that you can bind (or connect) sockets more than once, to different transports. So a `PUB` socket can quite happily send to `SUB` clients that are both local `in-proc`ess threads, other processes on the same machine via `ipc`, and to clients on remote machines via `tcp`.

There are other things that you can do. If you use the `ZMQ_FD` option from [here](http://api.zeromq.org/master:zmq-getsockopt), you can get `ZMQ_EVENT` notifcations in some way or other (I can't remember the detail) which will tell you when the underlying connection has been successfully made. Using the file descriptor allows you to include that in a `zmq_poll()` (or some other reactor like `epoll()` or `select()`). You can also exploit the heartbeat functionality that a socket can have, which will tell you if the connection dies for some reason or other (e.g. crashed process at the other end, or network cable fallen out). Use of a reactor like `zmq_poll()`, `epoll()` or `select()` means that you can have a pure actor model event-driven system, with no need to routinely check up on status flags, etc.

Using these facilities in ZMQ allows for the making of very robust distributed applications/system that know when various bits of themselves have died, come back to life, taken a network-out holiday, etc. For example, just knowing that a link is dead perhaps means that a node in your distributed app changes its behaviour somehow to adapt to that.